# Should I delete a question if I made a crucial error in it?

Tags: support, questions, deleting-posts

Should I delete my question, [Description for a verbal tic that is vernacular among young people in the U.S](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/368493/112436)?  Should I post a new one?  Should I rewrite the original one?

I made an important mistake in posing the question.  I described the mistake in an edit to the question.

Comment: The current question has answers, if you have a different  query just ask a new question.

Comment: It's only a single word "and", why would you need to rewrite a new question? Just make the edit, I don't see any crucial harm, the answers are not invalidated. You don't even need to write the word "edit" because users can easily check the post's history.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Could you move this to an answer, please?

Comment: @aparente001 I might have, but your second and recent edit is definitely more substantial. Accept Andrew's answer, we say pretty much the same thing about the edit, only his answer covers more ground.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot delete that question. You can only delete a question while it is unanswered, or it has only one answer which has not been upvoted.

**Where you can delete the question,** it is reasonable at least to consider doing so. The system allows it. If it has an answer, you should bear in mind the effort taken in providing it. You may not feel any pang of conscience over a one-line answer; but you should seriously consider whether an answer with quite a lot of research behind it should simply be removed.

You should avoid editing a question which has already been answered, if your edit would invalidate the answers, or require them to be edited too. People have answered the question you asked, in good faith. If your edit does not invalidate the answers, it's reasonable to make it.

Note that questions should stand on their own as a coherent whole. You should not mark edits with the word "Edit" — the edit history is available to see previous versions. It shouldn't be necessary for readers to do their own mental editing ("Oh, I know the answer to that! Ah, the question's changed; now, which bit does that affect?")

Where it's not possible to change the question without invalidating answers, by all means ask a new question. Reference the original, and make it clear that the new question is different (so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate). I would recommend a structure such as

> In my question [link], I asked X and answers explained Y and Z. However what I should have asked was A. Answers Y and Z don't answer that because B. What is the answer to A?

Comment: Re *avoid editing a question which has already been answered*, I'd say that if the edit was done to ***clarify***, and it turns out that the clarification invalidates answers which were predicated on invalid assumtions now ruled out, there's some justification in allowing those "premature" answers to collect downvotes. Where there's obvious ambiguity it's usually better to seek clarification through *comments* rather than steaming in with an early answer that may turn out to be irrelevant.